# JSON ajax SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, serialization, param

All I am trying to do is to build an object from the input elements typed in by the user without them clicking submit. These functions supposed to do the job, except I am not getting the $_POST array correctly at the host page:

I started out thinking I can create a simple json object and stringify it then ajax it as a 'json' datatype.  That did not work.  I kept getting parser errors, 'unexpected character ..'. I used an outside parser to check the generated object, and it was valid every time. 
So I modified my serialization to create a jquery.param object as you see below.

The output in console.log looks like this:

```
 [ [{ hostname: 'myhostname'}, {userdb1:'mydbname'}, {adminname:'guest'}, {adminpassword:'abc123'}, {username:'muuser'}, {password:'myuser'} ]
```

The var_dump[$_POST] at the host is this:

```
  Array ( [0] => [ [1] => { [2] => [3] => h [4] => o [5] => s [6] => t [7] => n [8] => a [9] => m [10] => e [11] => : [12] => [13] => ' [14] => m [15] => y [16] => h [17] => o [18] => s [19] => t [20] => n [21] => a [22] => m [23] => e [24] => ' [25] => } [26] => , [27] => [28] => { [29] => u [30] => s [31] => e [32] => r [33] => d [34] => b [35] => 1 [36] => : [37] => ' [38] => m [39] => y [40] => d [41] => b [42] => n [43] => a [44] => m [45] => e [46] => ' [47] => } [48] => , [49] => [50] => { [51] => a [52] => d [53] => m [54] => i [55] => n [56] => n [57] => a [58] => m [59] => e [60] => : [61] => ' [62] => g [63] => u [64] => e [65] => s [66] => t [67] => ' [68] => } [69] => , [70] => [71] => { [72] => a [73] => d [74] => m [75] => i [76] => n [77] => p [78] => a [79] => s [80] => s [81] => w [82] => o [83] => r [84] => d [85] => : [86] => ' [87] => a [88] => b [89] => c [90] => 1 [91] => 2 [92] => 3 [93] => ' [94] => } [95] => , [96] => [97] => { [98] => u [99] => s [100] => e [101] => r [102] => n [103] => a [104] => m [105] => e [106] => : [107] => ' [108] => m [109] => u [110] => u [111] => s [112] => e [113] => r [114] => ' [115] => } [116] => , [117] => [118] => { [119] => p [120] => a [121] => s [122] => s [123] => w [124] => o [125] => r [126] => d [127] => : [128] => ' [129] => m [130] => y [131] => u [132] => s [133] => e [134] => r [135] => ' [136] => } [137] => [138] => ] )
```

what is going on here. need to get a $_POST array of these key/value simple  user created object without form serialization!

Here are the functions

```
    function savePageInputs(idtags,targetOutId)
    {
        var method = 'post';
        var phpscript = 'savedata.php';
        var data = new Array();
        for(var i=0;i<idtags.length;i++)
        {
            tag = idtags[i];
            data[i] = $(\"#\"+tag).val(); //get their values
        }

        jsonData = makeJsonData(idtags,data); //make JSON object
        shipJsonToHost(jsonData, phpscript, method, targetOutId);
    }
    function makeJsonData(idtags,values)
    {
        tag = idtags[0];
        val = values[0];
        jsonData =  '[{ '+ tag +': '+'\''+val+'\'}' ;
        for(var i=1;i<idtags.length;i++)
        {                                
            tag = idtags[i];
            val = valueList[i];
            jsonData += ', {' + tag+':'+ '\''+val+'\'}' ;
        }
        jsonData +=  ' ]' ;    
        return jsonData;
    }
    function shipJsonToHost(jsonData, phpscript, method, targetOutId)
    {
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        var outputTo = $(\"#\"+targetOutId);
        outputTo.append('<center>Processing...<br/> <img src=\"images/loading.gif\" height=50 width=50></center>');
        $.ajax
        (
            { 
                data: $.param(jsonData) ,
                type: method, 
                dataType: 'text',
                url: phpscript, 
                success: function(response) 
                {                         
                    outputTo.empty();
                    outputTo.append(response);
                },  
                error: function(request, errorType, errorThrown)
                {                
                    outputTo.html('Error: '+errorType+ ' '+errorThrown);
                }
           }
        );  
    }
```

Comment: sorry about that, that was a cut and paste error on my part from the console.log

Comment: try setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = false;` or removing it (false by default)

Comment: unfortunately that did not make a difference .

Comment: Because you're passing a nested array, it's quite complex when you serialize in url-encoded format and depends on the server to be able to parse it. Consider sending the json string to the server and the server could parse that json string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not forget the actual syntax of the json

- `[{test: 1}]` is invalid
- `[{'test': 1}]` is invalid
- `[{"test": 1}]` is Valid
- `[{"value": 'test'}]` is invalid
- `[{"value": "test"}]` is valid

try to replace all your single quotes in your makeJsonData function by some double quotes; usually that does the trick

Comment: Thank you. I realized that and fixed it.  I also found that it does not like spaces between the value and '}'.  It is very restrictive.  At any rate, I switched to 'text' and $.param encoding which delivered an unformatted data stream to the php script in the $_POST host variable.  reformatting it was really easy: $hostdata = implode('',$_POST) then myarray = json_decode($hostdata). That took care of it